# Send message over bluetooth without pairing linux

Tags: linux, bluetooth

Is it possible to send a message over bluetooth without pairing on linux?

I need the receiver to get asked if we wants to receive some file or message, without being asked for a password.

Comment: Would you like walking down a street and getting bombarded with file send requests on your bluetooth-enabled phone? Because that's what'd happen if you could do things between two BT devices without pairing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the devices are already bonded (i,e perviously paired and link keys stored internally) then the user will not be asked for password each time.

If you want to do a transfer with unknown devices in unsecured way , then it is not possible- Bluetooth imposes security requirement for all application data exchange.